# How can I insert an input in sublime compiler

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext2

I started to use sublime text 2 editor today to write c/c++ programs, but when I run this code

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    int n;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     printf("%d\n",n);
     return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the compiler to ask for an input. 
but instead, it just prints the initial value of (n) which is garbage.
How can i insert an input ?

Comment: Something like [this](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what you want to do is input data in the same panel where `Sublime Text` show results, well friend, you can't.

The only thing you can do is configure `Sublime Text` for running the compiled program in an external terminal. The link chris provide you is a good start.

On the other hand when you say: *expecting the compiler to ask for an input*, is a conceptual error.  The compiler is not whom is expecting the input. The input is being expected by the **compiled program**.